# The address bar in File Explorer disappeared and I cannot figure out how to get it back

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

It happened a few days ago... I'm always installing new software so I really can't pinpoint it.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Windows 11 22000 -
Ryzen 5950X -
64GB RAM

Comment: I think something has damaged your file explorer.  Try DISM / SFC to see if that helps.  .....  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: No; That’s not the issue. Click on “This PC”; This behavior is controlled with a File Explorer setting

Comment: Not on my Windows 11 machines.  In Windows 11 Pro, the address bar in File Explorer appears to be fixed and cannot be turned off. I check Production and Insider. My machines may be different than yours.

Comment: Also Windows 11 Pro was updated today (November Patch Tuesday) to V22000.318 from .282 and that may have changed things. I checked File Explorer a couple of times.